# how to handle logged users in Swing

Tags: java, swing, code-injection

i have a Login Dialog that is visible when someone open the program, and it has the login/password, if your login is correct, JFrame will be visible and Dialog hidden/disposed...

in my case now, i use a method to send the users to the JFrame

loginDialog:

```
if(loginTrue) {
  MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
  mf.setLoggedUser(User);
  mf.setVisible(true);
}
```

and

mainFrame:

```
public void setLoggedUser(User user) {
  this.user = user;
}
```

ok its ok!

but in my dumb idea of MVC doing a lot of .class that will represent a different JPanel for the CardLayout, when the program is loaded it construct all the panelClasses1 to 10, inside the CardLayout

so I have to add the `setLoggedUser(User user)` for all the classes

and do:

```
panel1.setLoggedUser
panel2.setLoggedUser
panel3.setLoggedUser
panel4.setLoggedUser
panel5.setLoggedUser
panel6.setLoggedUser
...
```

Is there a way to change and remove all this code and use something similar to @Inject

Answer (score 0):

If there can be only one login user, you can declare the variable **user** in one place e.g. like a static variable in class MainFrame. Or you can define a collection of MainFrames for better interface if there can be more login users.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a better architecture look to Java Authentication and Authorization Service (JAAS):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html

This might be over kill if you are not writing a production application, but I would use something like this if it will ever be released into production.